# Help with Intergrals

Tags: calculus

Could anyone help me with explaining how I get rid of the $-3$ on the following intergral. And what rule to use? And also could someone point me to the page where it shows me how to write maths symbols. As I cant find it.

$$\int (e^{2t} -3e^{6t}) dt$$

I have the answer:

$$\frac12e^{2t} - \frac12e^{6t} +c$$

But don't understand where the $-3$ goes.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, learn how to use MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is your original expression $e^{2t} - 3e^{6t}$? And is your result $\frac{e^{2t}}{2} - \frac{e^{6t}}{2} + c$? If so, I will provide an answer below.

Comment: I tried correcting your expressions. In case these are not what you had in mind, you may click on the edit and see how I changed your expressions, and make modifications :-) good luck.

Comment: @Liam Or do you mean $e^{2^t}-3e^{6^t}$? Please format your notation - this is why MathJax is so important: because it provides a clear-cut way of typing expressions on a computer, with no ambiguity.

Comment: Yes. It just has dt at the end of the expression. And that was my result.

Comment: Just to confirm - is Math-fun's answer correct?

Comment: Hello, I am going to learn mathjax. I just didn't know where to find it.

Comment: Here: (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You can find exponents and integrals in the appropriate section (just scroll down, there's lots!)

Comment: Math-fun answer is not what I got. Deepak has the result I got. But I don't understand where the -3 went.

Comment: @Liam I edited my post. I provided an explanation of the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int (e^{2t}-3e^{6t})dt &= \int e^{2t} dt - 3\int e^{6t}dt \tag1 \\
&= \frac{e^{2t}}{2} -3\frac{e^{6t}}{6} + C \\
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{2t} - \frac{3}{6}e^{6t} + C \\
\int (e^{2t}-3e^{6t})dt &= \frac{1}{2}e^{2t} - \frac{1}{2}e^{6t} + C
\end{align}$$

In the first term of $(1)$ we need to find a function whose derivative is $e^{2t}$. Let $g(t)=ce^{f(t)}$. So $e^{2t}=\dfrac{d}{dt}g(t)=\dfrac{d}{dt}ce^{f(t)}=cf'(t)e^{f(t)}$.

If we let $f(t)=2t$ then $g(t)=ce^{2t}$. Now, we know that $\dfrac{d}{dt}g(t)$ must equal $e^{2t}$ so $2ce^{2t}=e^{2t}$ which implies $2c=1\implies c=1/2$, so $g(x)=ce^{2t}=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{2t}$.

Same for the second term of $(1)$, $c=6$ in that case, so $g(t)=\dfrac{1}{6}e^{6t}$ and because $-3$ is multiplied by it, the final value of the term becomes $\dfrac{-3}{6}e^{6t}=-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{6t}$. And that's where the $3$ goes.

The other steps are only algebra.

Comment: Hello, You have a different answer Deepak. I am not sure which one is correct now.

Comment: no they have the same answer @Liam

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and trying to learn it. Is this the full workings out for the expression then?

Comment: yes.....the full workings @Liam

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your expression is $e^{2t} - 3e^{6t}$, the answer is correct.

Integration gives you: $\frac{e^{2t}}2 - \frac{3e^{6t}}{6} + c$

which simplifies to $\frac{e^{2t}}2 - \frac{e^{6t}}{2} + c$

by simple cancellation to the lowest terms (so that's where the $-3$ "goes").

Comment: Thank you. But don't I have to show workings out to how I lose the -3?

Comment: I watched a video and came with that answer. But it didn't show any workings out. So that's why I didn't understand.

Comment: You can show working as I have. Do you *understand* my working?

Comment: Do you get that $\int e^{kt}dt= \frac{e^{kt}}{k} + c$ where $k$ is a constant? That's all I'm applying here to each term (when terms are added together, you work out the integral of each term then add, I'm sure you know this).

Comment: Yes I understand now. Thank you for your help.